# With PNP JS, How do I handle odata.null return values?

Tags: spfx, pnp, typescript, pnp-js-core

I'm using @pnp in my SPFX project, and I need to get tenant property. The code is as followed:

```
sp.web.getStorageEntity('mytenantproperty1')
      .then((prop: StorageEntity) => {
    //How do I handle odata.null?
      return prop.value;
});
```

If the key doesn't exist the results I get back is

> Object {odata.metadata:
>   "https://_________.sharepoint.com/sites/ASite/_a…", odata.null: true}
>   odata.metadata:"https://________.sharepoint.com/sites/ASite/_api/$metadata#Edm.Null"
>   odata.null:true
>   **proto**:Object {constructor: , **defineGetter**: , **defineSetter**: , …}

I've tried to check odata.null value but it doesn't appear to be there. So how do I check for invalid key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `odata.null` in the prop object itself.

Using this snippet you can check for invalid key:

```
sp.web.getStorageEntity('mytenantproperty1')
      .then((prop: StorageEntity) => {

        console.log(prop);

        if(prop["odata.null"]){
          // storage entity doesnt exist

          // do something (like create entity or return empty string)
          return "";
        }

        // storage entity exists, return its value
        return prop.Value;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. These documentations always shows the happy path, but never how to handle issues.